# Ajax call not refreshing form data

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to use ajax - apex:actionfunction to update related account when opportunity is selected.

```
<apex:form id="myForm1">
<apex:pageBlock id="myPageBlock1">
 <tr>
      <td width = '25%'><span class ='grayNormal'><b>Related Account</b></span></td>
      <td align="left"><apex:inputField id="RelatedAccount" value="{!Comp__c.Related_Account__c}" style="width: 150px;" /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width = '25%'><span class ='grayNormal'><b>Related Opportunity</b></span></td>
      <td align="left"><apex:inputField id="RelatedOppy" value="{!Comp__c.Related_Opportunity__c}" onchange="populateAccByOppy()"/></td>
    </tr>
 </apex:form>
 </apex:pageBlock>
```

javascript:

```
function populateAccByOppy() {
      var nameOfRelatedOppy = '{!$Component.myForm1.myPageBlock1}';
      var selctedOppy = document.getElementById(nameOfRelatedOppy+':RelatedOppy_lkid').value;
      if(selctedOppy != '')
          getAccNameByOppyId(selctedOppy);
  }
```

class:

```
public PageReference getAccNameByOppyId(String ids) {
       Comp__c comp =(Comp__c) stdCtrl.getRecord(); 
       system.assert(selectedOppyId != null);
       system.debug('selectedOppyId :: '+ selectedOppyId );
       Opportunity oppyAc = [Select Id, account.name from opportunity where id =:selectedOppyId ];
       comp .Related_Account__c = oppyAc.account.Id;
       return null;
   }
```

but it is not refreshing related account field

Comment: At which point you expect the `getAccNameByOppyId(String ids)` method to be hit? I can't see where it's being called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, a common mistake --

```
public PageReference getAccNameByOppyId(String ids) { ...}
```

You can't directly call controller methods with arguments in Visualforce.

Your Javascript `function populateAccByOppy() ..` needs to invoke an actionFunction such as:

```
    <apex:actionFunction action="{!getAccNameByOppyId}" name="getAccNameByOppIdActionFn" 
                         reRender="myPageBlock1" > 
        <apex:param name="oppoId" value="" assignTo="{!selectedOppoId}"/>
    </apex:actionFunction>
```

e.g. ..

```
 function populateAccByOppy() {
   var nameOfRelatedOppy = '{!$Component.myForm1.myPageBlock1}';
   var selctedOppy = document.getElementById(nameOfRelatedOppy+':RelatedOppy_lkid').value;
   if(selctedOppy != '')
      getAccNameByOppIdActionFn(selctedOppy);
 }
```

and you'll need to add to your controller a property

```
public ID selectedOppoId  {get; set;}
```

and rewrite the controller method to be a proper actionMethod:

```
public PageReference getAccNameByOppyId() {
   Opportunity oppyAc = [Select Id, account.name from opportunity where id =:selectedOppoId ];
   comp .Related_Account__c = oppyAc.account.Id;
   return null;
}
```

actionFunction components are Javascript functions with the added benefit of being able to invoke a controller actionMethod and passing parameters to controller properties.

A useful reference is http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2011/07/passing-parameters-to-apex-method-from.html

Comment: @Corp1645, if i set rerender="myPageBlock1" for apex:actionFunction and if i have required field it in pageblock, it will throwing Validation error. if I set rerender="RelatedAccount", it is throwing error as: Formula Visualforce Error - Expression is required on the action attributes.

Comment: @Bharat - on the actionFunction, use immediate="true" to bypass required field validations, from doc: `A Boolean value that specifies whether the action associated with this component should happen immediately, without processing any validation rules associated with the fields on the page. If set to true, the action happens immediately and validation rules are skipped. If not specified, this value defaults to false.`